# Jasmine suddenly throwing errors, mostly on toHaveBeenCalledWith

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

We cleared and rebuilt our dependency trees yesterday, and we've suddenly starting seeing these types of jasmine errors, mostly on calls to toHaveBeenCalledWith.

20) should call callback on modal success
     Email Campaign Preview Controller  showSuccess function
     TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'allKeys[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/)') in node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 2988)
public/assets/src/emailcampaign/email-campaign-preview.spec.js:200:41

I've upgraded all my jasmine and karma related packages.  I'm hoping someone here might've seen something similar in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Bug with array equality checking in jasmine 2.5.0 - take a look at the issue in github: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1195

For now, you can revert jasmine to 2.4.1 in your package.json.